# Help with a regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got the following sequence I'm attempting to detect...`#hl=b&xhr=a` where b is equal to anything and a is equal to anything.

I've got the following.. but it doesn't appear to be working... `(#hl=.+&xhr=)` Does anyone know why?

I'm using javascript and values a and b are letters of the alphabet.

Comment: Can you give an example of input that should work but doesn't?

Comment: Regex questions should be tagged with the target programming language, since libraries used to differ (please read the tooltip on the regex tag).

Comment: »Doesn't work« is *very* vague. Please state what you expect and in what way the observed behavior didn't match your expectations. I just tested your regex against the string you posted and it matched. Do you want to extract substrings from that (maybe the *a* and *b*)? In that case your parentheses need to be different.

Comment: The MYYN: In more complex cases I'm inclined to agree, but not for something this trivial.

Comment: That pattern [appears to work just fine](http://regexr.com?2sv78). What language are you using? Are you sure the syntax is good?

Comment: With a second `.+` it works in ruby: http://rubular.com/r/CCRKppmWfw Maybe it's matching too much then? But then we need to have more context.

Comment: @Joey: Alright, just seemed to be ok to indicate this fact here in general.

Comment: @Joey: Even for trivial ones. Some regex engines require that you use `\+`, for instance, where JavaScript uses `+`. It doesn't get a lot more trivial than that.

Comment: T.J.: That's news to me. Never seen that. Of course, some languages allow regex literals while others put them in strings but that doesn't change the actual expression, only its representation.

Answer (score 2):

`(#hl=.+&xhr=.+)`, you missed the second `.+`. Depending on your regex engine, you should also see their escaping rules, often the braces or the + have to be escaped. If you just want to match a whole string, the braces are not needed anyway, btw.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to be more specific to get a better answer:

- what programming language are you using RegEx in?
- what values can `a` and `b` have? Anything implies that newlines are included, which `.` doesn't match
- do you want to get the values of `a` and `b`?

Now that that's all been said, lets move onto a regex with some assumptions:

```
/#h1=(.+)&xhr=(.+)/
```

This will match a string `#h1=a&xhr=b` and select the `a` and `b` values from the string. It will be greedy, so if there are key-value pairs in the pseudo-URL (I assume it's a url encoded string as a hashtag) they will be matched in `b`.

```
#h1=a&xhr=b&foo=bar
```

the second selection will match `b&foo=bar`.

The regex also assumes `#h1=` comes before `&xhr=`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming #, & and = are special characters, how about this regular expression:

`#h1=([^#&=]+)&xhr=([^#&=]+)`

Are you sure your key/value pairs (?) are always in this order without anything in between?